# Use include? instead of a tracker

Tags: ruby

```
def add app
  @has_app[app] = true
  @apps << app
end
```

In [the code above](http://github.com/rack/rack/blob/3d000c5690715be1f1424ce70b08a702c8528d03/lib/rack/cascade.rb), instead of using

```
@has_app[app] = true
```

to keep track of the presence of 'app', couldn't we also say:

```
@apps.include? (app)
```

and do away with `@has_app`?

I'm trying to understand why this separate variable is needed here at all (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the extent of the code, then yes, you could simply use the `include?` method. This is redundant data. It could be, though, that this hash of booleans has some different meaning that's not clear from these lines of code.

There would be a performance difference (for large lists), as a hash lookup is faster than an array lookup as the size increases. (You'd need to double check Ruby specifics, if this is important).

Answer (score 1):

Methods with question-marks just check the state of variable instead of modifying it. Thus `@apps.include?(app)` would return either true or false depending on the array having the given object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with you. @has_app? is not a must. The only reason I can think of why the original coder used it is for performance's sake. Note that :

```
 @has_app is a Hash 
 @app is an Array.
```